# 2 Файла слить в третий и отсортировать по возрастанию

Tags: c, файлы

Создал 2 файла отсортировал их по убыванию теперь нужно слить их в третий сортируя по возрастанию как мне это сделать?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

FILE *f1;
FILE *f2;
FILE *f3;

#define N 9 
#define M 18

int qsort2(const void * a, const void *b)
{
    return (*(int*)b - *(int*)a);
}

int qsort1(const void * a, const void *b)
{
    return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

int main()
{
    int a[N], x, r, c, a2[N];

    f1 = fopen("D:\\fileforc.txt", "rt+");

    for (int r = 0; r < N; r++) 
        fscanf(f1, "%d", &a[r]);

    qsort(a, N, sizeof(int), qsort2);

    for (int r = 0; r < N; r++)
        printf(" %d", a[r]);

    fclose(f1);

    f2 = fopen("D:\\fileforc2.txt", "rt+");

    for (int r = 0; r < N; r++) 
        fscanf(f2, "%d", &a[r]);

    qsort(a, N, sizeof(int), qsort2);

    printf("\n");

    for (int r = 0; r < N; r++)
        printf(" %d", a2[r]);

    fclose(f2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это код, как вы их создаёте. Покажите код, который вы уже написали для вашей задачи.

Comment: Может Вам это надо? Многопоточная  сортировка слиянием : https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC

Answer (score 1):

У Вас есть два файла, отсортированных по убыванию.

1. Слейте их в один, так же, отсортированный по убыванию. Это тривиально.
2. Полученный файл перепишите в обратном порядке. Это тоже тривиально.

Получите один файл, отсортированный по возрастанию.

Comment: А как слить в один?

Comment: **А как слить в один?** - это называется "сортировка слиянием". Совсем просто: Открываем на чтение оба исходных файла. Открываем на запись результирующий файл. Читаем из обоих и сравниваем записи. Запись одно файла пишем в результат. По тому файлу, из которого сделали запись, переходим к следующей - читаем её. Повторяем до тех  пор, пока не кончились записи в обеих исходных файлах.

Comment: мои файлы отсортированы уже мне нужно переписать их в третий

Comment: Я же уже написал - как...  Что непонятно?